# Number of elements in vector of strings starting the same

Tags: r, string, matrix, vector, character

Let's consider vector and its combinations of degree 3:

```
string_vec <- c("huge", "big", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge")

combinations <- utils::combn(string_vec, 3)
```

now in those combinations I have elements that have two elements starting the same e.g.

```
# Those two start with "big"
> combinations[,4]
[1] "huge"     "big"      "big_huge"

#Those two start with "small"
> combinations[,5]
[1] "huge"       "small"      "small_very"
```

I want to have my matrix `combinations` but with such cases omitted.

**My solution**

```
# Empty vector to store not wanted indexes

idx <- c()

# For each combiation I will go through all elements in string_vec 
# and see weather there are not no two elements starting the same

for (i in seq_len(ncol(combinations))) {
  for (j in 1:length(string_vec)) { 
    starts <- startsWith(combinations[, i], string_vec[j])
    if (length(starts[starts == 1]) > 1) idx <- append(idx, i)
  }
}
```

And as you can see below it really solved the issue:

```
> combinations[, -idx]
     [,1]    [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       [,6]         [,7]         [,8]       
[1,] "huge"  "huge"       "huge"      "huge"      "huge"     "huge"       "huge"       "huge"     
[2,] "big"   "big"        "big"       "small"     "small"    "small_very" "small_very" "something"
[3,] "small" "small_very" "something" "something" "big_huge" "something"  "big_huge"   "big_huge" 
     [,9]        [,10]        [,11]       [,12]       
[1,] "big"       "big"        "small"     "small_very"
[2,] "small"     "small_very" "something" "something" 
[3,] "something" "something"  "big_huge"  "big_huge"
```

However I found this solution very inefficient due to the fact that double loop were used.

I wonder if there is a solution which can omit one loop are even do the same without any.

Could you please help me with finding the solution to have same output but with more efficient code ?

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for your answers. I found your codes very cleaver. I'm just dealing with one more problem if I define `string_vec` in the way following:

```
string_vec <- c("huge", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge", "big_very")
```

And then applying Ronak Shah's code and extracting very last element

```
do.call(cbind, combn(string_vec, 3, function(x) {
  if(any(colSums(sapply(x, function(y) startsWith(x, y))) > 1)) NULL else x
}, simplify = FALSE))[, 16] 

"something" "big_huge"  "big_very"
```

gives me two vectors starting with `"big"` which is sensible, because it's now no `"big"` in `string_vec`.

I wanted to modify that so it can work:

I extracted the starting characters up to `"_"`

```
k <- unique(sapply(strsplit(string_vec, "_"), "[", 1))
```

and then tried to apply your code but with comparing to `k`

```
do.call(cbind, combn(string_vec, 3, function(x) {
  if(any(colSums(sapply(k, function(y) startsWith(x, y))) > 1)) NULL else x
}, simplify = FALSE))
```

Could you please judge if I've done it correctly ?

Comment: You only want to check for values at the start of the string? column 7 and 8 have "huge" repeated, you want to keep it as it is?

Comment: Yes I want to have this kept! Only want to check for values with respect to their starting characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about removing the combination while using `combn` itself?

```
do.call(cbind, combn(string_vec, 3, function(x) {
  if(any(colSums(sapply(x, function(y) startsWith(x, y))) > 1)) NULL else x
}, simplify = FALSE))

#      [,1]    [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       [,6]         [,7]        
#[1,] "huge"  "huge"       "huge"      "huge"      "huge"     "huge"       "huge"      
#[2,] "big"   "big"        "big"       "small"     "small"    "small_very" "small_very"
#[3,] "small" "small_very" "something" "something" "big_huge" "something"  "big_huge"  

#     [,8]        [,9]        [,10]        [,11]       [,12]       
#[1,] "huge"      "big"       "big"        "small"     "small_very"
#[2,] "something" "small"     "small_very" "something" "something" 
#[3,] "big_huge"  "something" "something"  "big_huge"  "big_huge"
```

Comment: Hey Ronak! Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please have a look at my edit ? :))

Comment: Your code seems good. You then have words like `huge` and `big_huge` together but we are not concerned about the part of the string at the end, eight?

Comment: Exactly, just the starting characters are relevant for me ;)) Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```r
string_vec <- c("huge", "big", "small", "small_very", "something", "big_huge")
combinations <- utils::combn(string_vec, 3)

library(purrr)
tmp <- map_dfc(string_vec, ~colSums(matrix(startsWith(combinations, .x), 3)))
fltr <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x) !any(x > 1))

combinations[, fltr]
#>      [,1]    [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]       [,6]        
#> [1,] "huge"  "huge"       "huge"      "huge"      "huge"     "huge"      
#> [2,] "big"   "big"        "big"       "small"     "small"    "small_very"
#> [3,] "small" "small_very" "something" "something" "big_huge" "something" 
#>      [,7]         [,8]        [,9]        [,10]        [,11]       [,12]       
#> [1,] "huge"       "huge"      "big"       "big"        "small"     "small_very"
#> [2,] "small_very" "something" "small"     "small_very" "something" "something" 
#> [3,] "big_huge"   "big_huge"  "something" "something"  "big_huge"  "big_huge"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>